# How Do I get this ComboBox Hosted in a ListView to update my Collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a ComboBox hosted in a ListView and I need changes in the CombBox to update the supporing class that the ListView is bound to.

Here is my DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Category">
    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
              Style="{StaticResource DropDown}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Categories}}"
              SelectedValuePath="Airport"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Category}"
              />
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is the Listview.  The ItemSource for the ListView is a collection of Airports and is set in code behind, and has a property called Category that I need the combobox to update.

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Airport" Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category" Width="100"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource Category}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you set `SelectedValuePath` in your `ComboBox`? It's difficult to say without seeing your data structures, but that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this and I have appended the data structure below.

Comment: Nailed it!  Took out the SelectedValuePath and it worked.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data that supports the ComboBox and ListView.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

Class Window1

```
Public Airports As New ObservableCollection(Of Airport)
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    '*************************
    'Dummy data for testing


    Dim anAirports As New Airport
    anAirports.Name = "ABC"
    anAirports.Category = "AA"

    Airports.Add(anAirports)

    anAirports = New Airport
    anAirports.Name = "DEF"
    anAirports.Category = "BB"

    Airports.Add(anAirports)
    '*************************
    'Bind the airports to the list for display
    lstCategories.ItemsSource = Airports

End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class Airport

```
''' <summary>
''' Name of the Airport
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private mName As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return mName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mName = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Describes the type airport and is selected from a combobox
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private mCategory As String
Public Property Category() As String
    Get
        Return mCategory
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mCategory = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

''' 
''' Items that are to be displayed in the ComboBox
''' 
''' 
Public Class Categories

```
Inherits ObservableCollection(Of String)

Public Sub New()
    Me.Add("AA")
    Me.Add("BB")

End Sub
```

End Class